# How to multiply a double with a BigInteger in Java

Tags: java

I want to multiply for example; 0.1 * 10^30

How do I achieve this?

0.1 is a double
10^30 is a BigInteger

Human input will be converted into a double value but the value needs to be multiplied by 10^30 for computation.

Human input can be 0.09172349 for example.

Comment: The answer is `10^29`. **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: 0.1 is an example. I would like to compute the figures based on human input. Also edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: How does the human input `0.09172349`. Humans type text, so at what point in the input process is that text converted to a `double`? Why not convert the text to [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), to prevent loss of precision? Then call [`movePointRight(30)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointRight-int-)?

Comment: Asking for clarification when the question lacks information is not "emotion". Only emotion shown here is yours when you say that.

Comment: @Andreas no you answered the question perfectly. I did not know BigDecimal exists. I am talking about Nathan Hughes.

Comment: @NathanHughes I just typed out the question unclearly. String > double > BigInt is the process. Will change it to String > BigDecimal > BigInt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to convert both to [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Please see the caveats and advice at [the Javadoc for BigDecimal(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-). You mention "human input"; if you can take that human input directly as-is, and avoid bringing `double` into the picture at all, then you should.

> […] the value needs to be multiplied by 10^30 for computation.

If you are always multiplying by 10<sup>30</sup> — that's a fixed constant — then you should use [BigDecimal.movePointRight(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointRight-int-).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Which you could have found by reading the documentation on BigDecimal.